# Send string from custom Adapter to Activity

Tags: android

I have a custom listView row which looks like this:

[image: customRow]

I have a customAdapter with the following getView method (not interesting parts were deleted)

```
@Override
public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    holder.viewProfileImageButton = view.findViewById(R.id.viewProfileImageButton);
    holder.viewProfileImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           String pubKey ((objClass_foundUsers)foundUsersList.get(i)).getPublicKey();
            Intent getToUserProfileIntent = new Intent(context,activity_1_3_my_profile.class);
            context.startActivity(getToUserProfileIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

When the user clicks on the first imagebutton in the row this user's profile should be displayed. In order to do this I get the publicKey of the user in the `onClick` method in my `customAdapter` and want to pass it to another `activity`.

When using

```
getToUserProfileIntent.putExtra("pubKey", pubKey);
```

in the onClick method in the customAdapter and

```
pubKey = getIntent().getExtras().getString("pubKey");
```

in my activity it throws a NullPointerException saying:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

How can I send the publicKey from this adapter to another activity?

Comment: you can implement click listener or an interface to send data to your activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can send your data using intents in adapters like this:

```
   Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, yourTargetActivity.class);
    mIntent.putExtra("pubKey", pubKey);
    context.startActivity(mIntent);
```

**OR:**

You can implement an **Interface** to send data to your activity:

```
 public interface OnButtonPayNowCallBack {
    void onClickListener(String pubKey);
}
```

add this to your adapter's constructor:

```
  try {
        this.mOnButtonCallBack = (OnButtonCallBack) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Calling Context must implement 
                 OnButtonBack");
    }
```

and then in your click listener:

```
holder.viewProfileImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
onClickListener(pubKey)
}
}
```

And in your next activity you get the data like this:
**incase of sending data through intents:**

```
   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String pubKey= extras.getString("pubKey");
}
```

**and incase of sending data through Interface:**

```
first implement the interface in activity then use it's override method
    @Override
    public void OnButtonCallBack (String param) {

       // add your functionality here.
    }
```

Comment: I think OP wants the data in another activity, not in the same one.

Comment: @Emil i have edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this you need to add data in your `getToUserProfileIntent` using **`getToUserProfileIntent.putExtra()`**

```
 Intent getToUserProfileIntent = new Intent(context,activity_1_3_my_profile.class);
 getToUserProfileIntent.putExtra("pubKey", pubKey);
 context.startActivity(getToUserProfileIntent);
```

than receive like this in your **`activity_1_3_my_profile`**

```
Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
if (data != null) {
    String pubKey= data.getString("pubKey");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for sending use this code

```
Intent getToUserProfileIntent  = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), activity_1_3_my_profile.class);
getToUserProfileIntent .putExtra("pubKey","pubKey");
startActivity(getToUserProfileIntent );
```

for getting data inside your activity use this code

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String pubKey= extras.getString("pubKey");
    //The key argument here must match that used in your adapter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 holder.viewProfileImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent getToUserProfileIntent = new Intent(context,activity_1_3_my_profile.class);
            getToUserProfileIntent.putExtra("pubKey", pubkey);

                v.getContext().startActivity(getToUserProfileIntent);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below answers hope it helps you.

```
if(getIntent()!=null) // at first to check data is in intent or not
{

if(getIntent().hasExtra("pubKey")) // to avoid crash if pubKey is not passing.
{

pubKey = getIntent().getExtras().getString("pubKey");

}

}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for sending data to another activity:

```
@Override
        public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

            holder.viewProfileImageButton = view.findViewById(R.id.viewProfileImageButton);

            holder.viewProfileImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                   String pubKey = ((objClass_foundUsers)foundUsersList.get(i)).getPublicKey();

                    Intent getToUserProfileIntent = new Intent(context,activity_1_3_my_profile.class);
 getToUserProfileIntent.putExtra("pubKey", pubKey);

                    context.startActivity(getToUserProfileIntent);

                }
            });
        }
```

Below code for fetching data in another activity:

```
pubKey = getIntent().getExtras().getString("pubKey");
```